# What's the exact value of blood Ph and how is it corrected

Tags: blood, physiology

what is the exact value of the blood ph, how is it corrected and at what precision ?
Has there even been a real time high precision analysis of the blood ph ? where we could see the correction occurring in real time periodically on a graph, it would be awesome

Comment: [Wikipedia gives you 7.32 - 7.42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid%E2%80%93base_homeostasis). What do you mean with precision and correction? Are you talking about homeostasis of the body?

Comment: By precision I was meaning the decimal precision, but if wiki says 7.32-7.42 so it's a precision of +-0.1.  Yes I am talking about the homeostasis, how does the blood corrects itself after ingesting some food for example, I was wondering if we could see on a graph the real time correction occurring of the ph after getting disrupted, like is it happening linearly ?, etc...